# Flutter + Firebase - Mutate in-memory data model or rely on stream for rebuilds

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

In the example below, `CandidateData` is deserialized from a Firebase Realtime database using a Stream. Properties from it are used in building a `HiringManagerButton`.

```dart
class CandidateData {
  bool isEmployed;
  String name;
}

class HiringManagerButton extends StatelessWidget {
   final CandidateData data;
   
   const HiringManagerButton({Key? key, required this.data}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return ElevatedButton(
       child: Text('${data.isEmployed ? 'Fire' : 'Hire'} ${data.name}'),
       onPressed: onPressedFn
     );
   }
}

class SomeClass extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<CandidateData>(
      stream: fromDatabaseStream,
      builder: (context, state) => HiringManagerButton(data: state.data!)); 
  }
}
```

How should `onPressedFn` operate? Should it mutate the `CandidateData` model by changing the value of `isEmployed`, which causes the Widget to instantly rebuild, then make the service call to update the backend? Or should it just make the service call to update the backend, and rely on the Stream to provide an updated value to rebuild the `HiringManagerButton` with?

EDIT: Code for the two options above:
Option 1:

```dart
onPressedFn = () async {
  data.isEmployed = !data.isEmployed;
  await context.read<DatabaseService>().update(data);
}
```

Option 2:

```dart
onPressedFn = () async {
  await context.read<DatabaseService>().update(CandidateData(isEmployed: !data.isEmployed, name: data.name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go with option 2 as the database is the source of truth. Moreover, Flutter Firebase seems to have some form of offline consistency, which results in performance being a non-issue - DB writes are reflected instantly locally.